# how to use customized website name instead of IP Address on IIS

Tags: iis

I developed an Application locally with Angular-7. Eventually, I deployed it to the IIS of a VPS server with IP address 20.20.20.20 (not the real IP). When I run the application as 20.20.20.20, it works perfectly. 
Now I want to access the Application with customized name (ePortal). So on the IIS of the VPS server, I made the Host Name to be ePortal. When I typed http://jPortal on the browser url, I got an error that the page cannot be displayed and the url does not exist.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You host administrators must set up DNS properly so that http://hostname can actually map to http://10.10.10.7. Besides, your IIS site bindings must also be properly set up https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see your desired name on your local computer only please go to

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
```

And open hosts file using note pad having admin privilege.
and add your IP And your desired name to file and save it.
Now you can browse your server by the name you defined.

Comment: This guy is using a VPS server and ready for production. Don't give advice like this.

Comment: @LexLi He can do my solution on his VPS too.